# Programming with white text on black background?

Tags: editor

Does anyone program with white text against black background? I have heard some rumors that it is better for your eyes. What's the case? Is it any better than the traditional black on white? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: "traditional black on white"? Kids these days...

Comment: @Michael Mzorek: Heh, yeah. Well, I meant to say *colors on white*.

Comment: @Tower: Ever seen a computer running DOS?

Comment: @Tower I think "traditional" is probably green on black; grey/white on black is a close second

Comment: "traditional" is beads on string.

Comment: Also see [best-background-color-for-your-editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503103/best-background-color-for-your-editor?rq=1)

Comment: Traditional: black ink on paper.(well, maybe not for coding, but generally we are speaking about text editing here)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Traditional colors are black on white (cellulose paper) and black on light brown (papyrus). In the modern digital age, we can have any color combinations we please, but none of those are traditional. The main point of this question is clearly if it's better for your eyes to use darker backgrounds rather than lighter -- so let's not try to be too clever and stay on topic.

Comment: I'd also note 10 years ago all keyboards were shade of gray, and now cool ones are black. Probably you'd hardly find gray keyboard at market at all. So it clearly becomes a FASHION. 

I assume, that default color scheme of current-most-favorite-editor is fashionable. Check what Sublime did to the youth.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's actually white on black, or rather green or amber on black, that is the traditional way. I've used them all. :)

I believe that the use of black on white started in word processors, because it's a lot easier on your eyes when you alternate between looking at the screen and looking at source material printed on paper.

Also, the contrast between the screen background and the surrounding lighting should be small, so a white background works best with the well lit room most people use computers in most of the time. If you are programming in the darkness a black background would give less contrast, but then it's more a question of why you don't have proper lighting in your room...

There are of course personal preferences than can affect your choise of color setting, and your eyesight (or lack thereof) might also make one setting better than the other.

Answer (score 29):

There is an endless debate on [slashdot](http://science.slashdot.org/story/08/04/08/2213222/what-font-color-is-best-for-eyes) one can go through for all the unintelligible technical details (the more technical analyses seems to favour dark on light side though).

[This article](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/08/the-dos-and-donts-of-dark-web-design/), though about web designing, warns about the hazards of mindless black theming. The important aspect I understand is that the font is more important than coloring schemes. There is also disadvantage for black (not dark in general, but just pure black) background with white font **if font is thin**, since black creeps on to white and font would look a lil' blurry.

Despite all that, personally I find reading on darker background much easier for eyes. I don't think there is a definite answer for "light font on darker background" or vice versa. It will have to depend on personal tastes and habits more importantly. **For sure, the right scheme lets the font (the writing) to project to fore and subdues the background.** Now ask yourself is it dark on light that does this or light on dark? Here is the key, in that advocates who vouch for similarity with print suggesting that black outshines the white on paper, is blind to the fact that it is not the situation when it comes to electronic screen. Here the intensity of white beams on your eyes is much higher when compared to black.

And there is nothing like a best background color or fore color, but its the combination that matters. Right combination gives the right contrast, and contrast matters. And contrast should be sufficiently high, but not enough to be straining. Pure white on deep black can be hurting (the contrast being significantly high) but at the same time white on dark green is soothing. The same goes with amber on black.

Also when having a dark background it should be pale and not intense, so something like dark grey or teal will be better than black which in turn will be better than blue, red etc. Black on grey is excellent.

The [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) theme actually is after some good round of testing, going after their website. The good thing I love about **Notepad++** is that some of the better known themes like solarized, [zenburn](http://slinky.imukuppi.org/zenburnpage/), [vibrant ink](http://iunknown.com/2007/06/vibrant-ink-visual-studio-and-vim-settings.html) are available built in with the style configurator. **Obsidian is the best without a doubt btw! :)** [Catch it for Visual Studio here](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian).

Answer (score 13):

It seems to be a preference thing and possible environmental thing, honestly. You'll find people who believe each method is superior.

I know that personally, I have coded since the green-on-black and amber-on-black terminals were around, and now I use light gray text on black backgrounds wherever possible. I find black backgrounds to be extremely comfortable on my eyes even for very long sessions, but white backgrounds are very fatiguing. I have heard it described as "staring into a 100 watt lightbulb" and that's how it feels to me.

Room lighting can potentially have a significant effect also. Brighter rooms may lend themselves to brighter backgrounds, and darker rooms to dark backgrounds. It reduces the need for your eyes to struggle to switch between wide and narrow pupils required for bright then dark then bright as you occasionally look away from the monitor to relax your eyes (you should always do this, right?).

The best advice is to just try both, give it a week or so, and decide which you like better. If you find both the extremes are glaring, try using a more subdued theme than pure whites and pure blacks, try some softer grays.

Answer (score 13):

The quick answer is "dark text on white background suits more people".

My answer refers to this one: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/which-is-easier-on-the-eyes-dark-on-light-or-light-on-dark

As a person with astigmatism, I find white background with dark text is easier to read as the reference suggested. (I specifically experienced this after using the dark theme in visual studio 2013. It is so fuzzy to me that I had to change back to its 2012 default theme.)

Below are the quotes:

The science of readability is by no means new, and some of the best research comes from advertising works in the early 80s. This information is still relevant today.

First up is this quote from a paper titled “Improving the legibility of visual display units through contrast reversal”. In present time we think of contrast reversal meaning black-on-white, but remember this paper is from 1980 when VDUs (monitors) where green-on-black. This paper formed part of the research that drove the push for this to change to the screen formats we use today.

However, **most studies have shown that dark characters on a light background are superior to light characters on a dark background (when the refresh rate is fairly high).** For example, Bauer and Cavonius (1980) found that participants were 26% more accurate in reading text when they read it with dark characters on a light background.

> Reference: Bauer, D., & Cavonius, C., R. (1980). Improving the
>   legibility of visual display units through contrast reversal. In E.
>   Grandjean, E. Vigliani (Eds.), Ergonomic Aspects of Visual Display
>   Terminals (pp. 137-142). London: Taylor & Francis Ok, 26% improvement
>   – but why?
>
> People with astigmatism (aproximately 50% of the population) find it
>   harder to read white text on black than black text on white. Part of
>   this has to do with light levels: with a bright display (white
>   background) the iris closes a bit more, decreasing the effect of the
>   "deformed" lens; with a dark display (black background) the iris opens
>   to receive more light and the deformation of the lens creates a much
>   fuzzier focus at the eye.
>
> Jason Harrison – Post Doctoral Fellow, Imager Lab Manager – Sensory
>   Perception and Interaction Research Group, University of British
>   Columbia The "fuzzing” effect that Jason refers to is known as
>   halation.

It might feel strange pushing your primary design goals based on the vision impaired, but when 50% of the population of have this “impairment” it’s actually closer to being the norm than an impairment.

The web is rife with research on the topic, but I think these two quotes provide a succinct justification for why light text on a dark background is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that plus of programming and using white on black layouts causes less energy using.
Example of site saving energy by black layout is http://blackle.com/

Comment: It only uses less energy if you are using an old CRT screen. An LCD screen is back-lit and the liquid crystals blocks the light, so it uses the same amount of energy (or even slightly more) when the screen is black.

Comment: "In 2013 the majority of monitor sales are LED backlit LCD's which do not light up the parts of the screen that are black. Some older CCFL LCD monitors worked by wastefully backlighting the entire screen. Since 2005 manufacturers have moved away from CCFL's."

Answer (score 3):

well if you are programming when it is already dark outside then yes that rumor might be true becuase it is better for your eyes if the contrast between your monitor and room is smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Below mixed with my own thoughts and others.

- **Pure Black:**

  Pure white text on pure black is awful for **reading** (it's looks awesome on some graphs). Contrast is too high, and [pure black may looks unnatural](http://ianstormtaylor.com/design-tip-never-use-black/). So Visual Studio is using dark grey, just like Photoshop.
- **Visual Studio Team Says:**

  According to [The Visual Studio Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/05/29/visual-studio-dark-theme.aspx), dark editor themes are overall more preferred, reduced strain over long time usage is the top reason.
- **Emotional Expectation:**

  Emotionally, at least for some I guess: things related to creation with a dark theme may feels better, like those software; things books alike, e.g. blog or something, light background may better, since it's more expected.
- **Black for Colors:**

  For eyes, generally, I'm fine for both light and dark theme, since I'll always make sure the backlit not too light. As for Visual Studio, I guess the strain for eyes comes from the scanning of colors. You know, it's already hard to recognize all those colors (okay not that hard, you got the point), then there's that big fat white on the way, all the way. Guess eyes just have a "color sensitive mode", like people may not enjoy two white bars even if it's a light colored cartoon.

  **Light background easily makes things look clean, leads to higher readability for articles; dark background helps emphasize the color, leads to higher readability for codes.**

  One difference between blog and code text is that, codes are generally colored in a way it can standout its construction. Read an article will focused more on its meaning behind the words, but reading codes focus more on its visual construction and color, focus more on words itself. In photo editing and movie playing, dark colors provides less distraction. We treat codes actually more like a photo or video where visual matters more or even lots. Dark background fades away and makes the visual construction stand out.

Comment: Interesting thoughts here! It occurs to me that: 1. when I'm looking at code, I'm not reading it. I'm looking at structure, and I'll read, usually, small fragments of it; 2. Most modern systems provide syntax highlighting, and I suspect you have more options for contrasting highlighting on a black background.

Answer (score 3):

I use black background, because it wont strain my eyes. I used to regularly use white background, After 2 years, my eyes started getting strain. i tried to reduce the screen brightness, but it didn't help.

Finally i switched to black and now my eyes hardly even get stressed or watery (but still i'm going to wear spects soon)...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd give a little bit of my input.  Maybe it'll help someone.

Purely white background was starting to hurt my eyes from several hours of nonstop programming.  My vision was getting blurry to the point where I would have to stop.  I attempted to use darker themes, but it was harder to focus on text and that made it more difficult for me to scan through the code to find a particular bit.  Search functionality would not always work, because I might not know what I'm looking for (solving an exception-less bug, etc).

I looked around and found out that some gamers and programmers use yellow-tinted glasses.  Popular choice appears to be [Gunnars](http://shop.gunnars.com/computer-eyewear/l/100).  However, I didn't feel like spending $70 on a pair of glasses, because historically, my comfort zone with glasses is very narrow and I didn't feel like wasting my time or money.

So, further searching around brought me to [f.lux](http://justgetflux.com/).  It's absolutely free. The default settings were a bit too extreme for me and I couldn't get used to them even after two weeks.  However, after adjusting them slightly, I've been enjoying it very much.  During the day time, the screen is at its normal tone and intensity, but as the evening closes, it transitions into dimmer settings.  When I tried to test the difference (after getting used to it) by disabling it, it made it painful to look at the normal screen.  So, it does work. If you decide to give it a try... just try to use it for a few weeks before dismissing it.  It took me a while to get used to it.

Anyways, if you just can't stand darker themes, like me, those two options are probably a good way to remedy that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that black text on white background will not hurt your eyes, but using a black background for a long time, can make visual problems of your eyes.

Comment: I personally have felt this myself.

Answer (score 1):

B.K. brings up a lot of points that I too experience. First of which I know this is an older post, but it's still a relevant question. Secondly where I differ is I use a hybrid of darker and traditional lighter themes.

Personally I find darker background to be visually better. When I code I use this type of theme in my IDE [Dark Theme for Visual Studio 2010 With Productivity Power Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361918/dark-theme-for-visual-studio-2010-with-productivity-power-tools). The one thing that I do differently is I do not use the very dark code area or alter the coloring of the text. I go in and change my Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Plain Text > Item Background > Custom > Silver. This in turn gives me the aesthetically pleasing darker menus and such in the IDE but still makes my eyes focus on the code. It also keeps all the text and color coding that is native to the default IDE. This of course is for Visual Studio 2010. Newer versions or different IDEs have their own themes.

I have very light sensitive eyes and I tend to get headaches when coding all day without breaks. So I prefer toning the menus, tool bars, and side bars of an IDE to be darker. I also do use the [Gunnar](http://www.gunnars.com/) glasses.

There's quite a bit of evidence supporting that white background with darker text is actually better for your eyes in well lit office situations and such. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53264/dark-or-white-color-theme-is-better-for-the-eyes Has some very good sources listed throughout the responses on these studies. This is mainly concerning design for end users, but at the end of the day even though we are developers we are still end users of the IDE products and the same rules still apply.

So in conclusion it has a lot to do with your environment, your eyesight, and what you prefer. I personally use a dark IDE with a gray or silver work space with traditionally dark text. This makes it still easy to spot the contrast, but doesn't hurt my eyes by overwhelming me with white.

Comment: This is more of an opinion than a list of pros/cons like the OP wanted. Also, the post already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes the post does have an accepted answer, but it didn't provide the specifics I was looking for when searching for answers. The OP asked a multi-part question. I answered all parts of the question except the pros and cons and provided a link to a source that handled that aspect from another discussion. This is my opinion which answers the OP's questions "Does anyone program with white text against black background? I have heard some rumors that it is better for your eyes. What's the case?". The question requires an answer that is subjective and individual per case.

Comment: @mbomb007 Additional answers are allowed, even if there is already an accepted answer.  Nothing in the website rules prohibits that.  If that was the case, one would not be able to post an answer after a question has an accepted flag.

Answer (score 1):

On my laptop dark background create too much light reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It is really cool for your eyes.

White means full colour -- rgb(255, 255, 255) -- and black means no colour -- rgb(0, 0, 0). So when you are reading some black text against white background, the screen is flashing a lot of light except for a small portion (the text). On the other hand, when you are reading a white text against black background, the screen emits (almost) nothing except for the text area. That's why it looks so cool.

However, the contrast and environment lighting matter. Although I prefer white on black, both pure white on pure black and pure black on pure white have a high contrast, making things unreadable. In my personal experience, 'dark white' text on 'light black' would be the most suitable and long-readable theme for any environment.

Comment: "So when you are reading some black text against white background, the screen is flashing a lot of light except for a small portion (the text). On the other hand, when you are reading a white text against black background, the screen emits (almost) nothing except for the text area." - This only applies to OLED monitors.

Comment: AFAIK only OLED and similar screens (AMOLED, SAMOLED, etc) doesn't use backlight (the allways on lighting coming from behind the screen). That meaning that if you open 100% black image on LCD screen, the backlight still shining as bright as if you're open 100% white image. On the other hand, on OLED type monitors black image produces almost no light. Further read: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8795/understanding-brightness-in-amoled-and-lcd-displays and http://www.androidauthority.com/amoled-vs-lcd-differences-572859/

Comment: That's true. But I believe a small amount of backlight is good to keep the contrast in an optimum level.

Answer (score 0):

I used to program with

White background, I felt more tired and kind of flickering when going home and more tired.

Then I switched to Black background

Eye feels more relaxed and much less tiring and stressed.

I am not sure, which is good for eyes though.

Technically.
  When the background is Black the iris open more. I think it allows more radiation in. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using white background, because as a web developer you moving from browser to editor all the time and most websites are in white.

I tried to use black background and my eyes started to hurt, because of the switching between both editor and browser. (editor - black, browser - white)

I guess if you work just in black background for all your apps this might work